# Domínios com finais diferentes, apontando pra mesma hospedagem no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Pessoal tô com o seguinte problema eu tenho os seguintes domínios por ex: www.meusite.com.br e www.meusite.com, sendo que o Wordpress foi configurado para usar como principal o domínio '.com' .
Os dois domínios apontam para os mesmos DNS, e o site está abrindo nos dois domínios, mas quando eu clico em algum link interno, seja uma notícia ou page ele abre sempre pela url do domínio .com'. Teria como isso ficar dinâmico??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mateus, não é recomendando fazer isso. O certo é você ter um principal e seguir ele com os links. Porque?
O Google não gosta de conteúdo duplicado e dessa forma ele irá entender como dois sites com o mesmo conteúdo.

A forma correta de fazer é redirecionar um domínio para o outro.

Abraços

Answer (score 2):

Só precisa de editar o seu `config.php` onde está:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://meusite.com/wordpress' );
```

troque por:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wordpress' );
```

**Desta forma o Wordpress pegará de forma dinâmica qual o host no qual ele está.**

E se por acaso houver também :

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://meusite.com/wordpress' );
```

terá de fazer o mesmo.

**NOTA:**

Acredito que o ideal é você realmente manter um como o domínio principal (o qual quer que o seu site seja conhecido por) e usar o outro apenas como `parked domain` a maioria dos sites utilizam essa abordagem e não vejo um motivo prático para manter da forma como o usuário encontrou o site.